# Can you put a 3500W element in a 4500W water heater to run a 20 amp breaker on 12/2 wire?

Tags: electrical, water-heater

I have an A. O. Smith 40 gallon 4500W. Can I change the element to 3500W to run it on a double 20 with 12/2 wire?

Comment: As the answer says you can do it, it will take longer to heat up the water.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why not, depending on the length of your run.

I assume your run is in place, and you don't want to disturb it? Otherwise, I guess you'd just run #10 and keep the 4,500 watt element.

If your run is too long to pass 20 amps over #12, then it won't work. Consult length-of-run versus ampacity charts to be sure. But your 3,500 watt element should pull just 16 amps at 220 volts, so I imagine #12 is going to work for reasonable lengths.

Comment: Its only like 15 ft run

Comment: Yes wire already run

Comment: It is 240 not 220 how do i find lenth of run vrs amp

Comment: Yeah, you have to be going at least 180' before voltage drop is going to matter on a 240V circuit.